# error: function is inaccessible for derived protected Struct in C++

Tags: c++

I have

```
struct A { void ohai() {} };

struct B: protected A {};

struct C: private A { friend int main();};

struct D: B { void test() { ohai();} };

struct E: C { void test() { ohai();} };

int main() {
    A().ohai();
    B().ohai();
    C().ohai();
    D().ohai();    
    return 0;
}
```

However, I get the errors

```
error: ‘void A::ohai()’ is inaccessible
 struct A { void ohai() {} };
             ^
main.cpp:20:11: error: within this context
  B().ohai();
       ^
main.cpp:8:17: error: ‘void A::ohai()’ is inaccessible
 struct A { void ohai() {} };
             ^
main.cpp:22:11: error: within this context
  D().ohai();
```

I don't understand these errors. Because `B` inherits from `A` is protected, shouldn't it have access to `Ohai`? When I changed the inheritance to `public`, I got no errors

EDIT: [Difference between private, public, and protected inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/860339/difference-between-private-public-and-protected-inheritance) does not answer my question. According to that link, `B` should inherit `ohai` according to protected inheritance

Comment: `B` does but you do not.  You just can't call `ohai` from a `B` instance.

Comment: This is a duplicate, however I can understand why it is not clear to the OP.

The misunderstanding in the code, is that while ohai() is accessible WITHIN B, as it has protected inheritance - it is not accessible from OUTSIDE B.

That is - the line "B().ohai()" is now calling a protected function NOT a public one.

Answer (score 1):

The key about `private`, `protected`, and `private`, is understanding whether a class and its descendants understand that a class is subclassing something, versus whether external code to a class understands whether it is subclassing something.

Say we start with the class `A`:

```
struct A {
    void ohai() {};
};
```

Now `B` subclasses `A` with `protected`. That means that `B` and its inheritors understand that `B` is a type of `A`. Indeed, note how within the `foo` method, `this` is convertible to an `A *`:

```
struct B : protected A {
    void foo() {
        A *a = this;
    }
};
```

Now `C` subclasses `B` with `public`. Note how it also knows it is a type of `A` (because it knows it is a type of `B`, and it knows `B` is a type of `A`). We can again see that in its `bar` method:

```
struct C : public B {
    void bar() {
        A *a = this;
    }
};
```

Finally, `D` subclasses `A` publicly:

```
struct D : public A {
};
```

Up to now, we've considered how things look from inside the classes. Now let's see how they look on the outside.

Say we continue with:

```
int main() {
    A *p;

    A a;
    B b;
    D d;
```

Then, of course, `p` can point to `&a`.

```
    p = &a;
```

Since `D` subclasses `A` publicly, it can also point to `&d`.

```
    p = &d;
```

However, since `B` subclasses `A` protectedly, it does not know that it is a subclass of it. The following line fails compilation:

```
    p = &b;
}
```

It therefore leads to your error - it does not know that it is a subclass of it, and therefore doesn't know, from the side, that it has the `ohai` method.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are declaring A to be private in:

```
Struct C : private A{}
```

This makes A completely private and hence inaccessible to all of the structs accept C.

Comment: Nope. I just removed this line from the code and re-compiled, but I still get the error with `B().ohai()`

Answer (score 0):

Function `A::ohai()` is accessible to class `B` and classes derived from `B` because of the protected inheritance.  This is why `D::test()` is allowed to access `ohai`.

However, `main()` is not in the scope of class `B` or a class derived from `B`, so `main()` is not allowed to call `B().ohai()`.

What matters for access checking is the function you're calling from, not the object you're calling on.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot access private and protected data or functions from outisde directly. to do so you need to have a Getter in public scope.

B has a copy of A so it has ohai() but under protected scope so objects of B cannot access ohai(). (protected and private are inaccessible from outside but only public).

so writing B().ohai() will issue in a compile-time error.

A().ohai(): A can access ohai() because ohai is public-scoped remember structs by default they have public access to members unlike classes which are private by default.

C: inherits privately from A so all members of A() (public, protected, private) will be under private scope in struct C so if you write try to access one of them will issue in an error: trying to access private data. BUT main() is declared as friend to C so it can access all members of C private, protected and public. (friend function have a full access to the all members which they are declared friend to) eg

```
friend ostream& operator << (ostream&, myClass &rhs); // this function can access all members of myClass
```

D: inherits publicly from B so all members of B EXCEPT private will be in D (remember private members are not inherited) and B inherits protectedly from A so B cannot access ohai() directly (protect) and thus D cannot access ohai() because ohai() in B is protected.

if you write:

```
D().test();// it's ok because test() in D is public and test() is a member of D so it can access ohai();
```

E: inherits publicly from C so E can access everything in C but private, C inherits privately from A so all members of A will be private in c so all these members in C inherited from A will not be inherited. so E cannot access ohai() because it is inherited privately in C.